python not loading available .pyc file from __pycache__
I've never needed cached .pyc files until just now, but now I find they aren't working. I have a simple arrangement like a top level script mainscript.py:
import mymodule
mymodule.main()

and a mymodule.py file with some functionality:
def main():
    # do stuff

when I run python mainscript.py it takes about two seconds to compile, and then it runs and there is a __pycache__ directory containing mymodule.cpython-39.pyc
However, when I now repeat python mainscript.py, the same delay for compiling occurs, and yet the .pyc file in the __pycache__ is not updated to a new timestamp. My understanding is that the available .pyc file in __pycache__ should be automatically detected and imported, saving the two seconds of compile time. But, I'm apparently not getting that savings.
According to chatgpt there's about 5 things to check:

Remove the -B Option and unset PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE (I never used -B in the first place)
Delete Outdated or Corrupt .pyc Files (I did a rm -rf __pycache__)
Run Python from a .py File instead of interactively (never ran interactively to begin with)
Verify File Permissions (they are all default, did a chmod -R 755 anyway, no effect)
Force Compilation Before Importing (i used py_compile module to do this, no change)

I have checked all of the above and none are the answer. This is python 101 stuff it couldn't possibly be simpler, but somehow i'm just not seeing it (and neither is chatgpt).

If your .pyc modify time isn't changing, then it must be using it.  If it weren't, then it would be recreated with a new time.  You're jumping to the conclusion that your startup time is mainly due to the time it spends parsing mymodule and converting it to a .pyc file.  You seem to have disproven that theory.

use cProfile to profile the startup time, if you have done that already you will know if that is infact the bottleneck. Beyond that I agree with Tom, startup times can vary depending on variety of factors including system memory and CPU cycles available. If 2 seconds is too much time for startup you should consider alternate approaches like keeping the script warm etc.

I am using cProfile, and also tried exiting out of the script with a fake error condition right after the import to be sure of the startup time. I also tried running interactively, in which case the compiled script is cached in memory, and there I do see the time savings on the second pass. If the argument is that reading a 20 kB bytecode from disk takes the same amount of time as compiling it, then I guess that's what I'm stuck with. Been using python for quite a while without being an expert, and this one kind of blind-sided me.
